# Unable to Dynamically Load or Lazy Load a component in Modal

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, ionic4

I am trying to load a component via the Ionic ModalController lazily by just providing the name of the class as `'LocationComponent'` instead of the class.

I get the following error when I launch the modal

```
No component factory found for LocationComponent.
Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

However, if I use the class instead, I am able to load it.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-lazyload?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.page.ts

In `home.page.ts`

```
openModal() {
  this._modalCtrl.create({
    component: 'LocationComponent'   // Error: No component factory found for LocationComponent.
                                      // Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    // component: LocationComponent
  }).then(modal => modal.present());
}
```

I have defined the `entryComponents: [LocationComponent]` in `components.module.ts`

How can I get it to load lazily?

Answer (score 1):

Angular keeps component factories in a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) dictionary where **key is component type not string**

```
this._factories.set(factory.componentType, factory);
```

So using:

```
component: LocationComponent
```

should work for you.

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-lazyload-4qtthv?file=src/app/home/home.page.ts)**

Comment: But this is not lazily loaded. I would like to lazy load the component

Comment: You have already imported ComponentsModule in your lazy HomeModule and LocationComponent is part of ComponentsModule